# add double quotes around variable in link VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Im new to VB.NET, I need to add a variable to a dynamic a href tag like so:

```
litLink.Text = "<a href='" & Link & "' ></a>"
```

this code as of right now places single quotes around the link.

Comment: This is not the same question, doubling the double quotes doesnt work in my case with a variable.

Comment: You should be able to use what you have... it should still work but if you want double quotes then use litLink.Text = "<a href=""" & Link & """ ></a>"